# Module not found when using sudo on Raspberry Pi (Buster), Kernel 4.19, python 2.7

Tags: python

I'm Getting

> ImportError: No module named lirc

when running

```
sudo python myprog.py
```

But when I run

```
python myprog.py
```

(without sudo)

I don't get the problem. I have to use sudo because my code requires root to get an uncached set of available wifi's.

Any idea what the problem could be please?

Comment: What is the `PYTHONPATH` environment setting when running with sudo?

Comment: Its blank John, I checked on 3 different machines and its all the same. I'm trying to keep everything as out-of-the-box as possible. But problem is solved as about to post.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
sudo -H pip2 install lirc
```

It seems to me that you dont have lirc installed on system level.

Comment: Thanks outeh, essentially that was it! You wouldn't necessarily know this unless doing infrared remote control stuff but it was sudo -H pip2 install python-lirc. Appreciate your help!

Comment: @KevinY I'm glad i colud help